# Javascript higher & lower variable conditionals odd console output

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some simple code that takes the id values of "`.somedivs`" and puts them into global variables to be sorted by the conditional statements, then to the console. Below you can see that I am getting some weird results and no matter what combination of conditionals I use I can't get it to work right. Seems so basic, I'm thinking I'm violating some law of js or i'm missing something obvious.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.somedivs').mousedown(function(){
      first = $(this).attr("id");
    }).mouseup(function(){
      second = $(this).attr("id");

      if(window.first > window.second){
        var higher = window.first;
        var lower = window.second;
        var process = 1;
      }else if(window.second > window.first){
        var higher = window.second;
        var lower = window.first;
        var process = 2;
      }else if(window.first === window.second){
        var higher = window.first;
        var lower = window.second;
        var process = 3;
      }


      if(higher > lower){
        var status = true;
      }else{
        var status = false;
      }

      console.log("process = " + process + " // " + "window.first = "+window.first+" / window.second = "+window.second + " // higher = "+higher+" / lower = "+lower + " // status = "+ status  );


    });
```

Console output, as you can see most of the lines are returning true when they should be false, if you look at the numbers themselves. I marked some of the ones that are wrong with the arrow ">". **Why is status true when it should be false?**

```
process = 2 // window.first = 0 / window.second = 1 // higher = 1 / lower = 0 // status = true
process = 3 // window.first = 2 / window.second = 2 // higher = 2 / lower = 2 // status = false
process = 1 // window.first = 2 / window.second = 0 // higher = 2 / lower = 0 // status = true
> process = 1 // window.first = 5 / window.second = 22 // higher = 5 / lower = 22 // status = true
process = 3 // window.first = 7 / window.second = 7 // higher = 7 / lower = 7 // status = false
process = 2 // window.first = 3 / window.second = 9 // higher = 9 / lower = 3 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 19 / window.second = 14 // higher = 19 / lower = 14 // status = true
> process = 1 // window.first = 5 / window.second = 11 // higher = 5 / lower = 11 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 35 / window.second = 23 // higher = 35 / lower = 23 // status = true
process = 2 // window.first = 13 / window.second = 17 // higher = 17 / lower = 13 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 32 / window.second = 24 // higher = 32 / lower = 24 // status = true
process = 2 // window.first = 17 / window.second = 18 // higher = 18 / lower = 17 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 22 / window.second = 18 // higher = 22 / lower = 18 // status = true
> process = 1 // window.first = 8 / window.second = 11 // higher = 8 / lower = 11 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 18 / window.second = 14 // higher = 18 / lower = 14 // status = true
process = 2 // window.first = 3 / window.second = 6 // higher = 6 / lower = 3 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 24 / window.second = 16 // higher = 24 / lower = 16 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 9 / window.second = 15 // higher = 9 / lower = 15 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 31 / window.second = 26 // higher = 31 / lower = 26 // status = true
process = 2 // window.first = 24 / window.second = 28 // higher = 28 / lower = 24 // status = true
process = 1 // window.first = 41 / window.second = 30 // higher = 41 / lower = 30 // status = true
process = 2 // window.first = 13 / window.second = 19 // higher = 19 / lower = 13 // status = true
```

Comment: smells like a race condition to me... but i'm not sure where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinik it is because of the type of the variable:

try :

```
first = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
```

and

```
second = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
```

Comment: seams to work, I tested it using http://www.inventpartners.com/content/javascript_is_int and it returned true, LIES!

Comment: when I used the function in the link above javascript read my variables as integers and it returned true, which was not the case, it lied.

Comment: I want to point it out that the function is_int() is correct. It is merely used for testing whether the value is a decimal figure or an integer. It is not for testing whether the type of value is a number or a string.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, 
Higher would always be higher (so status should always be true) no?
You're always affecting the highest value (according to the test) to higher.
So except for equality (process 3), status is always true.

The problem seems more like : **Why sometimes higher is not the highest number in the output?**

And that's coming from the point raised by Liangliang Zheng, you're comparing strings.
In order to compare strings, javascript compare them character by character, so for example in the first >

"5" is higher than "22" because, "5" is higher than "2".

If you want your code to work with the number value, then you'd use the parseInt method as suggested by Liangliang Zheng.

Edit: And if you want it to work with status being true or false depending of which is higher (and you don't care about higher/lower value) then

```
  var status=(parseInt(window.first)>parseInt(window.second));
```

should do the trick